# Implementing redirection on node viewing without affecting solr search indexing

Tags: redirection, search

My logic demands that for a specific content type provided a node (Ex) node/123 has one if its CCK field named web link with a URL value like http://someothersite.com in it, viewing the given node mysite/node/123 should redirect to the respective URL http://someothersite.com given in that field.

I've implemented this with a custom module's [`hook_nodeapi`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) `view` case to check the value of the field and perform the redirect. However doing so has inadvertently affected my [apachesolr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) search indexing which invokes the hook on view condition (through [`node_build_content`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_build_content/6)) to generate the node for being indexed.

This has forced me to currently skip such specific nodes from not being indexed, however I wish to know if there's a better way of programatically implementing the aforementioned redirect without hook_nodeapi to keep the sanity of search indexing intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing this in `hook_init()` instead, eg, something along the lines of...

```
function YOURMODULE_hook_init() {

   $mgo=menu_get_object();

   if (!empty($mgo->type) && $mgo->type=='THE_TYPE_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR') {

      if (!arg(2)) { // eg so we ignore node/###/edit etc
        if (!empty($mgo->field_THE_FIELD_YOU_ARE_REDIRECTING_TO[0]['value'])) {
          drupal_goto($mgo->field_THE_FIELD_YOU_ARE_REDIRECTING_TO[0]['value']);
        }
      }
   }

}
```

Caveat:  I've never used apachesolr, so you may need to wrap this with further logic to make sure you are running when a user actually goes to the page, eg, arg(0)=='node' and is_numeric(arg(1)) kinda stuff.

ADDITION:

You might be able to just check args inside nodeapi() as well, eg:

```
if (arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && !arg(2)) { 
  // do your magic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate and well thought response, I was shying to use `hook_init` and was curious to know if there was some hook that would be better suited or tailor made for the occasion that I might have missed googling or finding from the API..